# Binding DataGrid.CurrentItem

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, key-bindings

All,

I have a DataGrid with it's CurrentItem property bound to some property in my VM.  I also have an ICommand that creates a new object, adds it to the collection that the DataGrid's ItemSource is bound to, and sets CurrentItem equal to the new object.

Everything is working great, except that for some reason Commits are not being called when changing the CurrentItem binding via code.

See relavent parts of code below.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemSource={Binding} CurrentItem={Binding Path=CurrentItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChange, Source={StaticResource VM}}>
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command={Binding Path=AddNewItemCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource VM}} Key="OemPlus" Modifiers="Control" />
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

VM:

```
Class cVM:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    /*...RaisePropertyChanged(string str) method implimented here to handle PropertyChanged event*/

    private ICommand _AddNewItemCommand; //defined in Constructor.  Adds new item to Collection and sets CurrentItem property.     
    ICommand AddNewItemCommand{ get { return _AddNewItemCommand; } }

    private object _CurrentItem;
    public object CurrentItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _CurrentItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _CurrentItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
        }
    }
    /*...*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a pure MVVM solution, but here is what I did to resolve my issue:

```
<DataGrid ItemSource={Binding} CurrentItem={Binding Path=CurrentItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChange, Source={StaticResource VM}}>
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command={Binding Path=AddNewItemCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource VM}} CommandParamater={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Key="OemPlus" Modifiers="Control" />
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Then in my ICommand (which is a type-safe RelayCommand, see code at bottom) I execute:

```
param => { param.SetCurrentValue(DataGrid.CurrentItemProperty, null); param.Dispatcher.DoEvents() /*An extension that pushes a dispather frame with dispatherpriority.background, which forces events to fire that might be in an asynchronious call-stack */; Object obj = new Object(); /*Whatever your Object is, of course */ MyCollection.Add(obj); CurrentItem = obj; }
```

Anyway, I hope this helps the next person.  I don't know if the DoEvents extension is required in this case, but I called it just to be safe.  Also, for param, my code knows it is DataGrid because I included a version of RelayCommand that takes Generics in the constructor

(Type safe relaycommand, if interested.  Found somewhere on the Internet, so can't take full credit)

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private Action<T> _execute;
    private Predicate<T> _canexecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canexecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canexecute = canexecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canexecute == null) return false;
        else return _canexecute((T)parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }
}
```